# I would if she would

Tags: phrase-choice

Is it possible to say *I would go if she would go*, or does it need to be *I would go if she came*?

And how about *we could save more if she could budget better* instead of *we could save more if she budgeted better*?

Comment: In your first example, are you sure that the second sentence isn't, "I would go if she went"?

Comment: Yeah good point.  But in English came and went can be used to mean the same thing at times since we are both going to the same place...well at least that's how i felt.  kinda like bring and take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I would go if she would go" is fine. "I would go if she came" might be ambiguous. Do you mean, "I would go if she would go with me"? That is, I wouldn't go alone. Or do you mean, "If she came here, then I would go someplace else?" That is, I don't want to be around her so if she came here I'd leave. In the first case I would say, "I would go if she came along". In the second case I'd say "I would go if she came here", maybe even "I would go somewhere else if she came here".

RE budget: Both are okay. I think "... if she budgeted better" is  the better sentence. "... if she could budget better" could technically be understood to mean that she is capable of budgeting better, but may not actually do so. But people regularly say things like that to mean the person actually does it.

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, she is cute, so if she'd go then I'd go too because I like her.  That's the one :)

Comment: @GreenKhan Or if she's rude and ugly, you might say, "If she shows up here, I'm leaving immediately!"